# Use pylint3 for checking Python 3 code using flycheck

Tags: flycheck, ubuntu, debian

By default, flycheck uses `pylint` for checking python code. However, the `pylint` program on Debian/Ubuntu is for checking Python 2, not Python3 (there is instead `pylint3` for Python3).

How do I configure flycheck to use `pylint3` instead of `pylint` for checking Python3 code?

Comment: I just tried installing `pylint` and `pylint3` on Ubuntu 17, and there wasn't a problem (Ubuntu calls the executable of `pylint3` with `3` in the end, so there is no name collision.) I'm not using `flycheck` with Python, so I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: @wvxvw the problem is not with installing pylint and pylint3. The problem is how to use pylint3 (instead of pylint) for checking python3 code using flycheck.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720869/emacs-how-do-i-set-flycheck-to-python-3#39024637